# auto.arima error: 'Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0'

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am trying to fit a dynamic forecasting model using auto.arima but I am getting the following error when trying to run my code:

'Error in solve.default(res$hessian * n.used, A) : Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0'

Here is my code:

```
library(forecast)

v1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
v2 <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
v3 <- c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
v4 <- c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

dynamicmatrix <- data.matrix(cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4))
dynamicmatrix

ts <- ts(dynamicmatrix[,1], start=c(2036,2))
dynamicmatrix <- data.matrix(dynamicmatrix[,-1])
fit <- auto.arima(ts, xreg=dynamicmatrix[])
```

The first column of dynamicmatrix contains the data that I want to forecast. The other 3 columns contain the data for xreg.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error?

Thank you,
Niels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

v1 = v2 + v3. So there is a redundant predictor causing a singular regression.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It helped me in solving the problem.